# ui-router with ControllerAs binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

ui-router State:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController as vm'
    });
```

In DashboardController I have:

```
var vm = this;
vm.title = 'Dashboard';
```

And in dashboard.html template:

```
{{vm.title}}
```

Why the result is showing "{{vm.title}}" instead of bind to it's value in controller?

Comment: if you want to bind it in view you shold use $scope

Comment: You need to add vm to scope to make it available in your view. $scope.vm = {title : 'Dashboard'};

Comment: $scope will die in new versions of Angular :(

Comment: ))) in any case I think use or not use $scope you will not be able to use your app with new version of angular, because beside of $scope in 2.0 will die lots of things

Comment: do you suggest any other router to a production project and keep more compatible with migration paths in the future?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a controllerAs setting when you configure the state.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: I tried your code, but didn't work, guess controllerAs is same that controler: 'DashboardController as ...'

Comment: Yeah - looks like you could use either method so it's something else. Can you post the full template instead of just the binding line?

Comment: binding line is my full template code for now, using for test

Comment: Very sorry, but I tested again and worked with controllerAs parameter, guess it was a cache problem. Marking as answer...

Comment: Using Ionic (march 2015), oddly controllerAs did not work when defining state, but — controller:"Controller as ctrl" — did.

Answer (score 1):

In your `controller function`, you will have to `return this;` at the end of the function.

```
var vm = this;
vm.title = 'Dashboard';
// 
return vm;
```

If we work with **$scope** instead of `vm = this;`:

```
$scope.title = 'Dashboard';
// 
return $scope;
```

Good Luck.